# How do I get the filepath of an uploaded file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-uploads

I'm having difficulty passing the path of a file to a library called Textract.

```
def file_to_string(filepath):
    text = textract.process(filepath)
    print text
    return text
```

Here is my upload form in views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    upload_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if upload_form.is_valid():  
        file = request.FILES['file']
        filetosave = File(file=file, filename=file.name)
        filetosave.save()
        if validate_file_extension(file):
            request.session['text'] = file_to_string(file) # something in here
else:
    upload_form=UploadFileForm()
```

models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.filename
```

Now Textract expects a path to go into `file_to_string(filepath)`. If I try to pass in the file object it gives me an error: `"coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found"`.

But if it is an InMemoryUploadedFile type, how do I get the path? I understand this is stored in memory and doesn't have a path.

How should I handle this -- should I save the file object first and then try to access it?
If I save the file and then try `request.session['text'] = file_to_string(file.name)` it gives a `MissingFileError`, though the docs say that this should give the name of the file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: try `request.session['text'] = file_to_string(fileobj.file)`

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński, thanks, added the models.

Comment: request.session['text'] = file_to_string(filetosave.file.path) should do the trick

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks, I tried that. But `request.session['text'] = file_to_string(filetosave.file)` gives 'coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found`

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński Thank you, that did it! If you will post the comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool mate ;), I've added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.session['text'] = file_to_string(filetosave.file.path)` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file_to_string(file.name)`.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name